# Trouble installing ubuntu 18.04 in Razer Blade 14 2017 (GTX 1060)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and there are so many problems with it (suspending issue, sound issue, graphic card issue, dual monitor issue, pcie error).
I resolved suspending and sound issue, but I can never fix graphics card, dual monitor issue, and pcie error.

For graphics card issue,

1. I tried simply choosing and downloading nvidia-390 driver in additional software - did not work
2. tried remove nvidia and reinstall by linux command below - did not work

   `sudo apt --purge remove nvidia*`

   `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
3. and I tried several other suggestions like blacklist-ing nouveau and install and other solutions. But none of them are working. `prime-select query` returns `nvidia`. But in settings-detail, `intel` one is being chosen.

For dual monitor issue, when I connect the second display to the laptop, it simply either 1. get crashed (display gets broken) or 2. does not do anything.

For pcie error, I edited `/etc/default/grub` and set the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
```

But did not fix the problem.

Can someone please tell me how to fix these problems?

Thank you.

Comment: After edit to `/etc/default/grub`, did you run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: PLEASE, how did you resolved the suspending issue ?

Answer (score 0):

btw i don't know how to fix this but when you do get it fixed there is razer RGB driver
here https://openrazer.github.io/ i don't know if it works for your laptop give it a try i got confused trying to download it maybe you will have better luck you could probably turn the RGB off if you're a monster and don't like RGB but for real its fine if you don't like RGB